# Need clarification on Australia's Temporary Skill Shortage Visa (subclass 482)

Tags: visa, working-visas, australia, skilled-migration, ielts

I want to check whether I am eligible for this visa or not. First of all, I am 28.5 years old, I hold an Associate's degree in my relevant field (Computer Programming) and I have +6 years of relevant work experience. I can get IELTS 6 in all bands.

My general status looks fine for the visa, but to be assured to step forward, I need to know the answer to these questions:

1. Does my wife need to pass any IELTS exam?
2. 482 needs a job offer from an employer who is willing to nominate you. Should I find the job myself? Or is there an online service or such thing by immigration department where I can find the employers who would nominate a worker of their need? Is it feasible to find a job inside Australia from outside? If yes, then how?